# Complement of a regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I have a regular expression that matches words consisting of letters that can contain one single quote followed by one or more letter:

```
([A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?)
```

This works fine, but what i actually need is the complement (for splitting a string into parts that match the above regex).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to split on the regex. The argument to the `split` method is the separator pattern, which is exactly what you want: What's left are the parts that don't match.

Comment: The `Regex.Split(input, "([A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?)")` does already split the `input` string into parts that do not match this regex. There's no need for compliment.

Comment: I think i misworded this. I want to split my String into parts that match the above regex. Which means i have to split on the parts that don't match the above regex.

Comment: Why not just use `Matches` to get all matches as a `MatchCollection`.

Comment: tokenize and match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all matches of this regex and extract the matched values:

```
var input = "a a 123123 123 3 122as'd";
var parts = Regex.Matches(input, "[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?")
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

// parts: ["a", "a", "as'd"]
```

Comment: Why do you use the collection `m.Groups` to access the individual match? You can achieve the same with simply getting `m.Value`. See this working example: http://csharppad.com/gist/2a0fa955a9f813e3c9abfab6f579e59e

Comment: Works great! Since i am coding in F# i had to change this code to `Regex.Matches(phrase, "([A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?)") |> Seq.cast |> Seq.map (fun (x: Match) -> x.Value)` to make it work.